# Grouping by two variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I'm trying to create a bar graph using `ggplot2` to show the occurrence of different consonants in some language data. For most subjects there is only one timepoint sampled, but for some of the subjects there are two timepoints. The subjects are grouped into two different groups for comparison, and their consonant production is grouped by `type` - a phonetic variable in my data.

I want to show the consonants produced by each subject in a stacked bar, and then have data from the speakers who were recorded twice show next to each other on the x axis. At the moment, `ggplot` is aggregating this data. I don't want to facet the data into two different plots.

```
 exampledata <- tribble(~subject, ~group, ~time, ~consonant, ~type,  ~n,
     "1", "A", 1, "p", F, 10,
     "1", "A", 1, "t", T, 12,
     "1", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
     "2", "A", 1, "p", T, 0,
     "2", "A", 1, "t", T, 45,
     "2", "A", 1, "k", F, 23,
     "2", "A", 2, "p", F, 2,
     "2", "A", 2, "t", T, 34,
     "2", "A", 2, "k", T, 56,
     "3", "B", 1, "p", F, 12,
     "3", "B", 1, "t", T, 13,
     "3", "B", 1, "k", F, 50,
     "4", "A", 1, "p", T, 10,
     "4", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
     "4", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
     "5", "B", 1, "p", T, 0,
     "5", "B", 1, "t", T, 24,
     "5", "B", 1, "k", F, 3,
     "5", "B", 2, "p", F, 23,
     "5", "B", 2, "t", F, 12,
     "5", "B", 2, "k", T, 7,
     "6", "A", 1, "p", F, 52,
     "6", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
     "6", "A", 1, "k", T, 64
     )
```

I'm currently using the following code, which generates the attached figure:

```
 plot1 <- ggplot(data=exampledata, aes(x=subject, y=n, fill=type, colour = group)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity") +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray87")) +
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("royalblue", "navyblue")) +
   theme_bw()
 plot(plot1)
 [![example bar plot][1]][1]
```

So all I want to do now is somehow create an extra grouping variable that shows `time` bars side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to work with a facet but removing the faced-like shape

```
ggplot(exampledata, aes(x= time, y=n, fill=type))  +  
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~subject, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") + 
  xlab("subject") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border =element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I was worried that this would look too full-on as I have a lot of subjects in my real dataset, but it looks great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data=exampledata, aes(x=subject, y=n, fill=type, colour = group, group = time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray87")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("royalblue", "navyblue")) +
  theme_bw()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: The plot looks wrong, right? The FALSE value of subject one is missing.

Comment: This is almost it but as @Jimbou says, the numbers don't stack correctly

Answer (score 2):

In @JAQuent's response, although elegante, the stacking is not preserved.
I propose this:

```
exampledata$interaction <- factor(interaction(exampledata$subject, exampledata$time),
                                  levels = sprintf("%d.%d", sort(rep(1:6, 2)), rep(1:2, 6)))

plot1 <- ggplot(data=exampledata, aes(x=interaction, y=n, fill=type, colour = group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(group = subject), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray87")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("royalblue", "navyblue")) +
  theme_bw()
plot(plot1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit of a hack, but this should do exactly what you want.

First your data needs to contain zeros for all combinations of subject, time, group and type. Like this:

```
exampledata <- tribble(~subject, ~group, ~time, ~consonant, ~type,  ~n,
                       "1", "A", 1, "p", F, 10,
                       "1", "A", 1, "t", T, 12,
                       "1", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
                       "1", "A", 2, "p", F, 0,
                       "1", "A", 2, "t", T, 0,
                       "1", "A", 2, "k", T, 0,
                       "2", "A", 1, "p", T, 0,
                       "2", "A", 1, "t", T, 45,
                       "2", "A", 1, "k", F, 23,
                       "2", "A", 2, "p", F, 2,
                       "2", "A", 2, "t", T, 34,
                       "2", "A", 2, "k", T, 56,
                       "3", "B", 1, "p", F, 12,
                       "3", "B", 1, "t", T, 13,
                       "3", "B", 1, "k", F, 50,
                       "3", "B", 2, "p", F, 0,
                       "3", "B", 2, "t", T, 0,
                       "3", "B", 2, "k", F, 0,
                       "4", "A", 1, "p", T, 10,
                       "4", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
                       "4", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
                       "4", "A", 2, "p", T, 0,
                       "4", "A", 2, "t", F, 0,
                       "4", "A", 2, "k", T, 0,
                       "5", "B", 1, "p", T, 0,
                       "5", "B", 1, "t", T, 24,
                       "5", "B", 1, "k", F, 3,
                       "5", "B", 2, "p", F, 23,
                       "5", "B", 2, "t", F, 12,
                       "5", "B", 2, "k", T, 7,
                       "6", "A", 1, "p", F, 52,
                       "6", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
                       "6", "A", 1, "k", T, 64,
                       "6", "A", 2, "p", F, 0,
                       "6", "A", 2, "t", F, 0,
                       "6", "A", 2, "k", T, 0
)
```

Then you basically draw two bar charts. Normally you would offset each with `position_nudge` to left and right to have to bars per subject next to each other. However, since the position argument is already taken ("stacked") the hack is to turn subject into a numeric variable, nudge directly with `as.numeric(subject) - 0.125` and `as.numeric(subject) + 0.125` and then format the x axis accordingly so that noone notices.

```
ggplot(exampledata,
       aes(fill = type, colour = group)) +
    geom_col(
        data = subset(exampledata, time == 1),
        aes(x = as.numeric(subject) - 0.125, y = n),
        width = 0.25
    ) +
    geom_col(
        data = subset(exampledata, time == 2),
        aes(x = as.numeric(subject) + 0.125, y = n),
        width = 0.25
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray87")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("royalblue", "navyblue")) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 6.5),
                       breaks = (c(1:6))) +
    xlab("subjects")
```